# Populate a range of data with values from another range of data

Tags: excel, vba

How do I populate a range of data with values from another range of data?

I am getting the value of B6 in all my source workbook cells.

```
Sub Read_External_Workbook()

'''''Define Object for Target Workbook
Dim Target_Workbook As Workbook
Dim Source_Workbook As Workbook
Dim Target_Path As String

'''''Assign the Workbook File Name along with its Path
'''''Change path of the Target File name
Target_Path = "D:\Profit&Loss March Import.xlsm"
Set Target_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Target_Path)
Set Source_Workbook = ThisWorkbook

   '''''With Target_Workbook object now, it is possible to pull any data from it
'''''Read Data from Target File


'''''Client
Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(3).Range("B6:B19,B26:B38,B39:B39,B42:B49,B50:B50,B54:B58,B59:B59,B86:B99")
Source_Workbook.Sheets(76).Range("K11:K24,K27:K39,K43:K43,K47:K54,K59:K59,K63:K67,K69:K69,K73:K86") = Target_Data

   '''''Process Completed
MsgBox "Task Completed"

End Sub
```

Comment: Excel does not like doing it that way.  You will need to break out each range group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the ranges into a list and iterate over it

```
Dim sSource() As String
sSource = Split("B6:B19,B26:B38,B39:B39,B42:B49,B50:B50,B54:B58,B59:B59,B86:B99", ",")

Dim sTarget() As String
sTarget = Split("K11:K24,K27:K39,K43:K43,K47:K54,K59:K59,K63:K67,K69:K69,K73:K86", ",")

Dim vData As Variant

For i = LBound(sSource) To UBound(sSource)
    vData = Target_Workbook.Sheets(3).Range(sSource(i))
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(76).Range(sTarget(i)) = vData
Next i
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: This worked great but what if I want to use the same ranges but apply them to different worksheets in the same source workbook. So, Instead of just Sheet (76), I need several others too.

Comment: You can create two arrays (one for source and one for target) of the worksheet numbers or names and add an outer iteration on them.  So the inner asignments would be `vData = Target_Workbook.Sheets(arrSource(j)).Range(sSource(i))` and `Source_Workbook.Sheets(arrTarget(j)).Range(sTarget(i)) = vData`.